# How to change the state in react native without useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

https://snack.expo.io/@miralis/eager-cashew

Check components/high.js pls.
I am trying to use "useState" here:

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(mid);
```

But, when i try to add setNumber(mid); to higher() and lower() functions, it brokes the code.
Bcs of when my number 25 and I click on higher, it is alerting 25050, but it must give 38.
Full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Alert, TextInput } from 'react-native';




export default function High() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(mid);
  const [max, setMax] = useState();
  let begin = 0;
  let end = max;
  let mid = (begin + end) / 2;
  function higher() {
    begin = mid;
    mid = (begin + end) / 2;
    alert(JSON.stringify("Your number is higher/lower " + mid.toFixed() + "?"));
        setNumber(mid);

  }
  function lower() {
    end = mid;
    mid = (begin + end) / 2;
    alert(JSON.stringify("Your number is higher/lower " + mid.toFixed() + "?"));
    setNumber(mid);
  }
  function start() {
    alert("Ваше число больше / меньше / равно " + mid + "?")
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{number}</Text>
      <View style={styles.start}>
      <Button
        title='Start'
        style={styles.start}
        onPress={() => start()} />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder='Write num here'
        onChangeText={text => setMax(text)}
        placeholderTextColor='#fff' />
      </View>
      <Button
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => {lower()}}
        title='Меньше' />
      <Button
        title='Больше'
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => {higher()}} />
      <Button
        title=''
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => alert("Легко!")} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 10
  },
  start: {
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: '#1E90FF',
    color: '#000'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are having trouble with types.

The onChangeText function take a **string** as an argument (https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext) but you need an integer. You can just add **parseInt**

```
<TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder='Write num here'
        onChangeText={text => setMax(parseInt(text))} //here
        placeholderTextColor='#fff' 
/>
```